Quantum Confinement
I have been reading about quantum confinement, and I came across two statements.

"Quantum confinement occurs when the dimension of the confining region is comparable to the wavelength of the electron."
"Quantum confinement occurs when the size of the particle is the same or smaller than the Bohr exciton radius."

What is the difference between these two statements, or are both of these statements true?

Where did you find these statements?

@MattHanson link here

Quantum confinement occurs when spatially confining boundary conditions are introduced that reduce ("squeeze") the effective extension of the system and thus wave function so that, e.g., a change in energy levels occurs. This can happen for waves when the system size becomes comparable to wave length, or for exciton wave function when the spatial confinement becomes comparable to the extension of the wave function.
